# A conflict exists with definition newBox in namespace internal

Tags: namespaces, definition, conflict

function makeABox(e):void {

if (e.name == "seri1"){

```
var newBox:karo1 = new karo1();
```

}else if(e.name == "seri2"){

```
var newBox:karo2 = new karo2();
```

}else{

```
var newBox:zemin1 = new zemin1();
```

}

ust_bar.addChild(newBox);

newBox.x = i*60;

newBox.y = s*60;

}

Answer (score 0):

Dee, you should make a question. I'm presuming you got problems with 'namespaces'. Try to define de variable first, with a superclass type, then in those conditionals just give a value. Like this:

```
    function makeABox(e):void {
        var newBox:somesuperclass;
        if (e.name == "seri1") {
            newBox = new karo1();
        } else if (e.name == "seri2") {
            newBox = new karo2();
        } else {
            newBox = new zemin1();
        }
        ust_bar.addChild(newBox);
        newBox.x = i*60;
        newBox.y = s*60;
    }
```

This is actionsscript3? If is, you probably need e.currentTarget.name.
Hope this helps.